# Translate the contourplot in 2d space

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I work with data stored in 3D matrix `D`. To visualized it, I plot a slice:

```
figure
contourslice(D,[],[],[15],10);
view(3);
axis tight
```

I know that the data stored in matrix is a single period of periodic data. Here I need a trick: having that slice, how could I translate it in 2D space up to several periods to see periodic structure of the data?

Say I have a slice of a shape `[A]`, but I need:

```
[A][A][A]
[A][A][A]
[A][A][A]
```

Is it possible to do during plotting phase, not touching actual data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the image processing toolbox, one simple way of visualizing the data in that manner would be using the [repmat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [montage](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/montage.html) functions.

Say you are interested in tiling slice 15 of D:

`montage(repmat(D(:,:,15),[1 1 1 9]));`

Alternately, you can just do

`imagesc(repmat(D(:,:,15),[3 3]));`

Comment: What is A here? Is that handle of the figure?

Comment: Sorry, You mentioned having a slice of shape [A], so I went with that.  I will update the answer to explain where A comes from

Comment: Thank you , I have found montage very useful for my case

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way which is more related to graphic processing using copying of axes objects

```
T=48 % that is a period
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:T,1:T,1:T);

% create nine figures with shifted axes
for j1=1:3
    for j2=1:3
        figure;
        contourslice(x+(j1-1)*T,y+(j2-1)*T,z,D,[],[],[15],10);
        a(j1+(j2-1)*3)=copyobj(gca,gcf);
    end;
end;


% combine content of each figure into a single one
figure('name','COMBINED');
axes;
set(gca);

for j=1:length(a)
    copyobj(get(a(j),'children'),gca);    
end;

% close others
close([1:9])
```